# ¿como editar un evento con eventdrop de fullcalendar y ajax?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, web, fullcalendar

estoy creando una aplicacion y necesito que se puedan mover los eventos del fullcalendar y editarlos, el codigo para editarlo ya esta y funciona, el problema es que al mover eventos y cancelarlos esta guardando los id de los eventos cancelados y al editar uno los edita a todos, hace el edit de todos como si fuera un ciclo, asi es mi codigo:

```
 eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
  var id_edit=0;
  $('#moverDia').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
  $('#titulo_edit').html(event.title);
  var fecha = event.start.format();
  var separador = "T";
  var resul = fecha.split(separador);
  $('#fecha_edit').html(resul[0]); 
  var horaI=$('#hora_inicioE').val();
  var horaF=$('#hora_finE').val();
 $('#aceptar_cambio').click(function(){
   id_edit=event.id;
 /*  $.ajax({
     url:"/editarC/"+event.id,
     type:"POST",
     data:{"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}",fecha_inicio:resul[0],hora_inicio:horaI,hora_fin:horaF}
   }).done(function(){
    alert('funciono :v');
   }).fail(function(){
     alert('no funciono  :v ');
   }); */
 });
 $('#negar_cambio').click(function(){

   alert('el tamaño es '+event.id);        
    revertFunc();
  });
},
```

no se porque al darle click en aceptar cambio los edita a todos, si alguien sabe porque pasa esto agradeceria mucho la informacion.